# Rails 5 API and Phonegap

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, phonegap-build, rails-api

Can anyone explain how or direct me to a tutorial that explains in detail how to connect a Rails 5 API to Phonegap.  I'm relatively new to Rails and have no experience with phonegap and have been looking for a few days now for something that explains this in detail.   I'm using HTML5, CSS and JQuery for the front-end.

Really appreciate any help.

```
    <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="com.yourname.workshop" version="1.0.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
    <name>Workshop</name>
    <description>
        A sample Apache Cordova application that responds to the deviceready event.
    </description>
    <author email="dev@cordova.apache.org" href="http://cordova.io">
        Apache Cordova Team
    </author>
    <content src="http://localhost:3001" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="1" />
    <access origin="*" />
    <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
    <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
    <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
    <platform name="android">
        <allow-intent href="market:*" />
    </platform>
    <platform name="ios">
        <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
        <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
    </platform>
</widget>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way you "connect" a front-end application that you write in Phonegap with a backend Rails API is with HTTP requests.

[Rails has an official guide for writing API-only applications.](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/api_app.html) Your app doesn't have to serve only an API, but it needs to serve some easily parseable data. (Usually JSON)

Then, you use a library on the front-end to make requests to specific endpoints defined by the backend API. You can then parse the responses to do whatever it is you need to do. [jQuery makes it easy to make requests.](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

In Rails, let's imagine I have a controller that allows your usual CRUD operations on posts of some blog or something. It might look like this:

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  responds_to :json

  def show
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    respond_with(@post)
  end

  def index
    @posts = Post.all
    respond_with(@posts)
  end

  def create
    @post = Post.create(params[:post])
    respond_with(@post)
  end

  def update
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    @post.update_attributes(params[:post])
    respond_with(@post)
  end
end
```

Now you can make HTTP requests to these actions from JavaScript (or anything else, for that matter):

```
$.get('/posts', {}, function(response){
  // response here is the data returned by the Post#index action
})

$.post('/posts', {post: {content: "post content"}}, function(response){
  // response here is the data returned by the Post#create action
})
```

This is a pretty basic example, but most web applications are just some variation of this concept.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this! Especially the example which helped.  So understanding all of that - might be a foolish question but how do I connect the controller/server to phonegap when I'm in development?  I inserted my config.xml file in an edit above.  Does that `localhost` line I added do the trick?

Comment: I've never used phonegap myself, so I can't say for certain. But if that sets the domain for all requests, then it should work